# How can you make an number equal a range?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, range

If I have:

```
(Time.now.year - CardSignup.last.dob.year) = 5
```

Then how come :

```
(Time.now.year - CardSignup.last.dob.year) == (1..6)
```

Returns `false` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two points.

1. You've got it flipped around.
2. Your missing a =

(1..6) === (Time.now.year - CardSignup.last.dob.year)

That should work.

Remember your sending a message to the range object (1..6) creates.

Comment: Or did I misunderstand your question?

Answer (score 4):

```
(1..6) === 5
```

triple equals (===) is the operator you are looking for. == is for comparing a range to a range.

=== is an operator of range which is why the (1..6) goes first.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Range.html#M000698

Answer (score 4):

A range is an array, versus a single value. A single value isn't truly equal to an array. What you may want is:

(1..6) === Time.now.year - CardSignup.last.dob.year

or

(1..6).include?(Time.now.year - CardSignup.last.dob.year)